# Using random.choice() in elif statements

Tags: python, discord.py

Im currently working on a command in `discord.py` that involves using many `elif` statements, and `random.choice()` inside of each. heres a snippet of my code:

```
if size == -1:
    sizetext = random.choice(negativetexts)
elif size == 0 or size == 1:
    sizetext = random.choice(microtexts)
elif size == 2 or size == 3 or size == 4:
    sizetext = random.choice(smalltexts)

print(sizetext)
```

and so on. The problem is that it isnt sending a response, or printing anything to the console. i looked around, but i couldnt find the solution to my problem. and yes, i have `random` imported. im not sure if `or` cant be used in elif statements, or im using elif wrong, or what. any help is appreciated.

im expecting the bot to send an embed and/or print whatever random string it chooses.

Comment: You don't appear to have said what the problem is. Also, please show a [mcve].

Comment: from the code you show, sizetext is only defined within the scope of the if, elif steps, you need to define sizetext before you execute the if statement in order to be able to print afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I can assume.

One is that (as far as I can see from the code provided) you are declaring the "sizetext" variable from within the if statement, and as a local variable, it can't be accessed from outside the if statement. The only thing is that I would assume the compiler would give an error of "sizetext" being undefined from the print command.

Two is that if you're trying to assign "sizetext" to a value that is empty, this will happen. You didn't provide enough information or code for me to evaluate properly, but there's a chance that the variables "negativetexts", "microtexts", and "smalltexts" are empty, OR aren't the proper type of value for random.choice to be run on. I would recommend adding text to the print, ex:

```
print("Value of sizetext: " + sizetext)
```

To troubleshoot and see if it's just sizetext being empty.

The only thing that confuses me is that you haven't received an error as far as was documented. Both of the cases would most likely lead to an error, so unless you have a try: except statement we can't see, I don't know. I might be overlooking something though.